# Meaning of "...went as bad as you can go"

Tags: meaning

In the movie Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone Hagrid says: "A few years ago there was one wizard who went as bad as you can go." What does "went bad as bad as you can go" mean? Why does he say "as bad as you can go"?

Comment: I edited the title of the question to make it match the actual quotation.

Answer (score 4):

*Went* is the past of *go*, in all its senses.

*Went bad* is the past of *go bad* (= *become bad*, colloquially)

So *Went as bad as you can go* = *became as bad as it is possible to become*.

*You* here is an indefinite pronoun, equivalent to *one*, (but much more common than *one* in everyday speech)

Comment: And understand that "go bad"/"went bad" is an idiom, as when bananas go bad and turn black.